# Launch various method with an other method

Tags: java, methods

I want launch various method(exercise) with an other method with Scanner.
When the machine asks which exercises, I want to answer with a tapping answer and when I say the exercise(method), the machine launch this method  with my tapping answer.

Exemple:
Which exercises?
me - "W34"
(The machine launches the method W34)

[image: CODE]

Comment: please do not put a link to a snapshoot but your code here

Comment: and scanner is used to read from an stream, in your case from the console (system.in)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! :) I suggest you add the code (as text) instead of linking to a screenshot. Also try to improve the readibility of your answer. I am sure you'll receive more answers then!

Comment: Please read this: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ and this: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode (these discuss why the question receives the downvotes you're seeing).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use reflection.

Note: For more please write your code in question I will change it accordingly

```
obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName).invoke.invoke(obj);
```

Comment: This will not compile, actually.

Comment: change obj with this or create the object of the current class and use where I am written obj.. Please add your code here

Comment: It won't compile even of all references to `obj` are replaced with something else. The Reflection API use here is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i m not a professional, and sorry for the code it was my first question on this site, i only put in some exercises because there are so many.

Code :

public class Main {

```
public static String CapitalizeEachWord(String st) {
    String result = "";
    st = st.replaceAll("() ([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
    String[] words = st.split(" ");
    for (String word : words)
        if (word.length() > 0)
            result += Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1) + " ";
    return result;
}



public static String Scann() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Wich exercises? (W + exNumb)");
    int x = in.nextInt();






    return null;
}

public static String W1() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    System.out.println("Antoine Sidot!");
    System.out.println();
    return null;
}
public static String W2() {
    int result = 74 + 36;
    System.out.println(result);
    return null;
}
public static String W3() {
    System.out.println(50/3);
    return null;
}
public static String W4() {
    System.out.println(-5 + 8 * 6);
    System.out.println((55 + 9) % 9);
    System.out.println(20 + -3*5 / 8);
    System.out.println(5 + 15 / 3 * 2 -8 % 3);
    return null;
}
public static String W5() {
    int nb1 = 25;
    int nb2 = 5;
    System.out.println(nb1 + " x " + nb2 + " = " + nb1*nb2);
    return null;
}
```

}